# How to correlate latitude and longitutdes of two different pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geopandas

I'm trying to correlate lat/long of 2 different dataframes.

The structure of my dataframes is this:

```
df1
  lat  long  
0  x  y  
1  x  y  
2  x  y  

df2
  lat  long  
0  x  y  
1  x  y  
2  x  y 
3  x  y
4  x  y
```

Each black and red dot below are lat/long pair and I want to find a correlation co-efficient between them. I also illustrated the dataframes to show that they have different numbers of rows.

I tried reading this article but was not capable of applying it to my situation: https://geographicdata.science/book/notebooks/06_spatial_autocorrelation.html

I also tried using pandas correlate but don't think it would work for my situation because I'm comparing 2 columns vs 2 columns.

```
corr = df[col1].corr(d2[col1])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is an algorithms issue. You can’t use a simple correlation algorithm on two sets of points with different lengths, period. The spatial autocorrelation algorithm you’re referencing has to do with values which are located in 2D. For example, how well is elevation correlated across two datasets for the same points. But you’re just asking about two sets of points with no dependent variable. Afraid you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Thanks Michael, do you have any suggestions on what I should be doing? Thanks @MichaelDelgado

Comment: No - the goal of correlating two sets of points of different lengths doesn’t make sense to me. This might be a question for [stats.se] - check out their guide of [how to ask](//stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: But if you do ask there you’ll need way more info about your actual goal, why you’re doing this, what you’ve tried, etc.